# What are the changes to Ibis 2.0?

Tags: ibis

The [Release Notes](https://ibis-project.org/docs/release/index.html) page on the Ibis project website does not describe the most recent update to Ibis (from 1.4 to 2.0). What are the changes?

Answer (score 1):

The [release notes](https://ibis-project.org/docs/3.0.2/release_notes/) are now posted (up to version 3.02)